# How to remove extra spaces between text in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to remove all extra spaces between text. Codebeautify gives me exactly what I'm looking for. How would I go about doing that in Notepad++? I’m having trouble finding a way to describe this precisely; see the link and use the sample or type a bunch of random words with 20 to 50 spaces between them.

https://codebeautify.org/remove-extra-spaces

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1429211/edit) and add sample text and expected result. A link to an external site doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Here a workaround that work on most of the software :
Open the "Search and Replace" function (CTRL+H), in the "Search" field type two space "  " and in the "Replace" field type one space " " then click on "Replace All" button as many time as you need to replace all the useless space (0 occurrences found).